# How can I get the name of an executable from a makefile?

Tags: vim, debug, makefile

I'm trying to configure vim to run "make debug" (which adds the '-g' flag to the rest of the CFLAGS), and then use Pyclewn to run "Cfile $filename here$" and then run it. This will allow me to quickly use Pyclewn to debug my programs.

I need a way for vim to be able to get the executable file-name compiled by the make-file.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to solve this is to add a `rundebug` target to your Makefile.

Depending on what you use to generate Makefiles (automake, cmake, or are you editing raw makefiles?) this may be easy to do.

E.g. in my own projects I do something like this:

```
add_executable(MylibTestExe EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL ${TEST_ALL_SRC})
target_link_libraries(TestExe ${MYLIB_TARGET} gtest ${COVERAGE_LIBS})
add_custom_target(test MylibTestExe DEPENDS MylibTestExe)
```

This creates a new executable, `MylibTestExe`, and adds a target `test` that depends on runs `MylibTestExe`.